# How to ensure firebase data is always an array?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime database that is an array, however when certain nodes are deleted, the data goes from array to dictionary.

Example:

Before:

```
[
   {
      "callDescription":"Call Zero",
      "callDuration":"call Zero",
      "callID":0,
   },
   {
      "callDescription":"ssadsad",
      "callDuration":"5-8 Minutes",
      "callID":1,
   },
   {
      "callDescription":"dfdsfdsfsd",
      "callDuration":"5-8 Minutes",
      "callID":2,
   }
]
```

Then the `callID: 0` & `callID: 1` nodes are deleted and it turns into:

```
{
   "2":{
      "callDescription":"dfdsfdsfsd",
      "callDuration":"5-8 Minutes",
      "callID":2,
   }
}
```

How can I ensure that the data remains an array regardless of nodes being deleted?

I am using swift, and my app expects an array, so any time a dict is received I get an error.

Here is how I am decoding:

```
class Service {
static let shared = Service()
let BASE_URL = "https://url.com"

func fetchClient(completion: @escaping ([Calls]) -> ()) {

guard let url = URL(string: BASE_URL) else { return }

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

    // handle error
    if let error = error {
        print("Failed to fetch data with error: ", error)
        return
    }

    guard let data = data else {return}

    do {
        let myDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        let calls = try myDecoder.decode([Calls].self, from: data)
        completion(calls)
    } catch let error {
        print("Failed to create JSON with error: ", error)
    }
}.resume()
}
```

Comment: How did you try to delete them?

Comment: They're deleted via a form inside the app using `ref?.child("calls").child("\(callID)").removeValue()`

Comment: const alwaysArray = data instanceof Array ? data : [data]

Comment: @DaniilLoban sorry I am using swift. My app expects an array so anytime the data changes to a dict I get an error.

Comment: @ZD let alwaysArray  = data is ArrayType ? data : [data] // does it work on swift?

Comment: @DaniilLoban This still causes the same error. I was thinking that I could somehow force the data to remain an array using the Firebase rules?

Comment: @ZD I think that It is Immpossible

Comment: did you get error on call myDecoder.decode([Calls].self, from: data) ?

Comment: @DaniilLoban only when the data is a dictionary, when it is an array it is fine. It becomes an array when certain nodes are deleted from the data which is very frustrating.

Comment: I think there should be 2 functions.

The first for the base case (item)

The second is for the array, which will call the first function.

Depending on the data type, you need to call either the first or the second function

Comment: @DaniilLoban that's a good idea. Will try that. Thanks